# C# - Simple MongoDB projection with automapping returning "Expression not supported"

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, map-projections

Im trying to execute a mongodb query with projection and I want to use automapper to map the model and the DTO.

Im using mongodbdriver 2.23

```
public class MachineOperationModel
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public EMachineStatus MachineStatus { get; set; }
    public EDevStatus DevStatus { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class MachineOperationDto
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<MachineOperationDto>?> Teste()
{
    var proj = Builders<MachineOperation>.Projection.Expression(m => _mapper.Map<MachineOperationDto>(m));

    var teste2 = await _collection
        .Find(Builders<MachineOperation>.Filter.Empty)
        .Project(proj)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

When I try to run the projection, I receive the following error:

> Expression not supported: value(AutoMapper.Mapper).Map(m).

Both classes are properly mapped with AutoMapper

```
private void MachineOperationMap()
{
    CreateMap<MachineOperation, MachineOperationDto>()
        .ReverseMap();
}
```

I've read a lot of stackoverflow questions but no answer has solved my problem

Comment: The project expression will be evaluated server-side, I don't think AutoMapper is available on the server.  For an example, see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/csharp/current/fundamentals/builders/#create-a-projection

Comment: Try `ProjectTo` instead.

Comment: you should remember that linq expression you provide should be transformed in mongo query language (MQL), in this case driver does nothing about method you provided and therefore can't translate it

Answer (score 0):

the projection is going to happen in mongo and auto mapper is not available in mongo engine. you can use below code :

```
Builders<MachineOperation>.Projection.As<MachineOperationDto>()
```